# Is there any opensource java restaurant management system is available

Tags: open-source, java, mysql

I want to do an online mini project in java which is for food ordering in  restaurant.

Specifications

**Customer:**
Place the order,
Pay the bill,
Review order places,

**Employee:**
Take the order,
Billing,
Delivery,

**Admin:**
Update software,
Install,
Modify any changes in the order or bill,

Is there any opensource web based system is available for above use? With mysql as DB

Comment: What devices will each of the actors use? Will the customer really interact with the software directly?

Comment: The customer will intact with the system. It is a web based system then there is no question of device.

Comment: Interesting. Please tell us more, as it is a very unusual restaurant type, and that will have an impact on the software too. For instance, can customers order the day before? Should the website require registration? Should it work on mobile? Can people eat before they pay?

Comment: This is a mini project for acadamic use.  I want to know is there any system already avail or not. If that system has user registrations and stuffs like that it is not a problem at all.

Comment: If the system has very poor ui also it is not a prob.

Comment: " It is a web based system" - so why insiat on Java? Maybe you cna find soemthing at https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=java+restaurant

Comment: @Mawg: The asker's requirement are very peculiar so I doubt a general Sourceforge search will do.

Comment: You are probably correct, Nicolaus, but I am not going to Google for him, and don't know of such an application, so I can only suggest SourceForge, GitHub ... FreahMeat, if that is still around  ...